# Dip Switch settings for furnace circuit board

Tags: hvac, furnace

I have a 2-stage variable speed furnace installed with single stage thermostat. I would like to control W2 staging time delay using dip (DIP) switch settings on circuit board, but there is a sentence that confuses me. It could be my bad English. If you could help, I will appreciate it.

Manual reads as follows:

> “Leave both switches off when using a 2-stage stat or enabling a W1
>   only call”

If I put both dip switches OFF (S7-1 and S7-2), does it mean that my furnace will never fire stage-2 and always be on Stage-1?

```
Following table is from the manual:
S7 Switches 1 & 2 for W2 delay.
-------------------------------
Switch Settings    | Options
----------------------------
[S7-1] |[S7-2]     | [Time]
----------------------------
OFF    | OFF       |  OFF
----------------------------
ON     | OFF       |  10 Minutes
-----------------------------
OFF    | ON        |  Auto
-----------------------------
ON     | ON        | 20 Minutes
--------------------------------
Note: S7-1 and S7-2 refer to dip switches.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct -- turning S7-1 and S7-2 both off will disable the second stage of heat on your furnace unless it's called for explicitly by turning the furnace's W2 input ON.

Since you have a single stage thermostat, the first setting I'd try is Auto -- i.e. S7-2 ON and S7-1 OFF.  That lets the furnace control board make a choice on its own regarding how long to wait before kicking the second stage of heat on.